# Mysql: Get all results that has all this relations

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
  objects                    object_features
-------------              -------------------
id                         id
name                       object_id
                           term_id
```

What I want to achieve is, giving a list of features, get all objects that has all of them.
I'm trying this:

```
SELECT objects.* 
FROM `object_features` LEFT JOIN `objects` ON ( objects.id=object_features.object_id)
WHERE term_id IN ('1','3','4','10')
```

This is the php code I'm using:

```
$feature_list = array(1,3,4,10);
$sql = 'SELECT objects.* 
FROM `object_features` LEFT JOIN `objects` ON ( objects.id=object_features.object_id)
WHERE term_id IN ('.implode(',', $feature_list).')';
```

This is near to what I need, but differing that it returns me any object that has any of the features given, instead of ALL the features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one option is to group by the data you want returned from object and add a having clause that counts object.id and tests to see if it is the same as the length of the array.

```
SELECT objects.id, objects.name 
FROM `object_features` LEFT JOIN `objects` ON ( objects.id=object_features.object_id)
WHERE term_id IN ('1','3','4','10')
group by objects.id,objects.name
having count(objects.id) = 4
```

Cant swear to the syntax on that as I've been writing tsql recently and don't have an instance of mysql to test on.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>try</strike>

```
'WHERE term_id = '.impode(' AND termid = ', $features_ids).')'
```

This will result in:

```
WHERE termid = 1 AND termid = 3 AND termid = 5
```

Actually you need a GROUP BY to group by each object and using a HAVING clause to allow only rows that have all the termids

```
SELECT objects.* 
FROM `object_features` LEFT JOIN `objects` ON ( objects.id=object_features.object_id)
WHERE term_id IN ('1','3','4','10')
GROUP BY objects.id, objects.name
HAVING count(term_id) = 4
```

Comment: I've already tried that but doesn't works. (Your first answer)

Answer (score 0):

The SQL way of doing it would be:

```
SELECT objects.* 
  FROM objects
 WHERE null not in 
   ( 
      select of.object_id
        from features f 
        left join object_features of on (f.id = of.id)
   )
```

Assuming you have a `features` table with all the features.

If you need to list only certain features, you can do (check out the where condition on the subquery):

```
SELECT objects.* 
  FROM objects
 WHERE null not in 
   ( 
      select of.object_id
        from features f 
        left join object_features of on (f.id = of.id)
       where f.id in (1,2,3,4,5)
   )
```

Comment: Sure, but I only want to list objects that have a limited list of features.

Comment: @clinisbut: then put a where in the subquery.